# IPV6 auto configuration not working in Ubuntu Natty

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, ipv6

In Windows 7, my computer can automatically get a IPV6 global address and use IPV6 network, but in Ubuntu Natty, I can't find out how to let stateless configuration work. 
My network is a university campus network,so I don't need tunnels. I think if one thing  can silently and successfully be accomplished in Windows, it shouldn't be impossible in linux.

By the way, this ubuntu natty is running in VMware workstation with vmware-tools installed. I heard somesone said vm-tools conflict with network-manager so I uninstalled network-manager.

I tried manually editing /etc/network/interfaces and used a static IPV6 address, and I can use IPV6 this way, but I just want to use auto-configuration.

I found this post:
[How to disable autoconfiguration on IPv6 in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/33196/how-to-disable-autoconfiguration-on-ipv6-in-linux)

and tried

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=1
```

but without any luck.

I got this in dmesg:

```
root@natty-150:~# dmesg |grep IPv6
[   26.239607] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[  657.365194] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[  719.101383] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[32864.604234] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[33267.619767] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[33341.507307] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

I am not sure whether it matters,but then I setup a static IPv6 address (with gateway) and restart network,I  ping6 ipv6.google.com and the ipv6 network is fine.This time a entry was added in dmesg

```
[33971.214920] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

So I guess the complain of no IPv6 router does not matter?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton no... that why I haven't accept an answer..

Answer (score 0):

Weird. I have a default install of Ubuntu 11.04 here and SLAAC / autoconf works out of the box:

```
sander@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:43:38:b7  
          inet addr:xx.xx.56.92  Bcast:xx.xx.56.95  Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: xxxx:xxxx:1:0:20c:29ff:fe43:38b7/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe43:38b7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:459 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:319 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:419159 (419.1 KB)  TX bytes:35138 (35.1 KB)
```

Are you sure the router on the network is sending out proper Router Advertisements? It might be that autoconf is actually not (properly) configured and Windows is falling back to DHCPv6.

Comment: Once I used wireshark and I am sure it's not DHCPV6..

Comment: I'm  puzzled too. It seems that almost nobody else have this problem? All that I can get from google is toturial telling you how to use some tunnels. By the way, this ubuntu natty is running in VMware workstation with vmware-tools installed. I heard somesone said vm-tools conflict with network-manager so I uninstalled network-manager.

Comment: My Natty test-box is also running under VMware with vm-tools installed, so that shouldn't be the problem. Can you use wireshark to see if your IPv6 router is sending Router Advertisements? Please include the details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up VMware to run your virtual machine networking in bridged mode. Then your VMs will be directly connected to the network and be able to receive router advertisements.